# DLL with invalid PDB path

Tags: windows, debugging, dll

I'm trying to get one of our old games to work so we can re-release it. It works other than the fact that when I initially run the executable, I get the following error message:

"*There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \Device\Harddisk4\DR4*"

Then when I click on either "Cancel" or "Continue" it then goes on to load the game and works fine.

So I loaded the exe into a disassembler, and it turns out to be when trying to load the symbols for granny2.dll.  Here's the callstack:

[callstack image http://www.dracan.co.uk/temp/grannybugcallstack.png](http://www.dracan.co.uk/temp/grannybugcallstack.png)

So it's trying to load granny2.pdb (which will be part of the [Granny 3D](http://www.radgametools.com/granny.html) library) from a drive/directory I don't have.

In our game directory, there's granny2.dll. So I ran that through Visual Studio's dumpbin utility, and that path is referenced in it:

```
Debug Directories

    Time Type       Size      RVA  Pointer
-------- ------ -------- -------- --------
40493D28 cv           37 00000000    5A400    Format: NB10, 3FF4AC61, 32, h:\build\granny\release\rt\granny2.pdb
```

I grabbed a few versions of this DLL from various online sources, and they all seem to have the same PDB path in the DLL.

Can anyone think of anyway of getting around this error message?

I'm running Windows7. A colleague is running Vista, and has just started seeing it but has run it last week without getting the error. Unfortunately he can't think of anything that's changed on his computer since. Another colleague who's running XP doesn't get this error at all

Thankyou for any help with this,
Dan.

Comment: I don't understand.  That call stack is all about the Debug Help Library; is this only happening when it is being debugged?

Comment: No, it happens out of the debugger too. I just loaded it into a disassembler to find out what the code was calling to cause that messagebox to appear. Once that messagebox appeared, I hit pause in the disassembler, and that's the callstack it gave me. Perhaps this is a red herring - but it is the same error message in or out of the debugger though.

Comment: So the game itself is trying to load its own debugging symbols?  Sounds a little strange to me.  What code is doing this - the game itself or the Granny 3D library?

Comment: I'm presuming the game is trying to load the DLL's debugging symbols. Although I'm not sure why if both the DLL and our game was compiled non-debug. Unfortunately our game's Exe was compiled a couple of years ago (I wasn't involved).

Comment: So where is SymInitialize being called from?  The stack doesn't go back far enough.  Do you have the source code to the game?  If so you could just use SetErrorMode and hopefully that would get rid of the dialog.  I still think it's rather odd that somebody is trying to load symbols, though.

Comment: Aha! I've been being blind, and not noticed the elibbase reference in that screenshot! That's another library which we do have the sourcecode for. Just grepped that, and found the SymInitialize call! Looks like it's some debug code that's trying to get the callstack. Not sure why on earth this is being run in a non-debug build though!! Will look further into it on Monday. Thanks for your help with this. Not sure exactly how to mark what you've written as the answer though, as they're all in comments. I've upvoted them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said this works on your collegue's XP machine, you may try running it in XP virtualization mode in win 7.

Comment: I tried it in compatibility mode, which didn't make a difference. Just tried installing the Virtual PC thing (I presume this is what you meant), but it's now asking me to reboot for the 3rd time - which takes about half an hour on this slow machine. Given that even if it does work in Virtualisation mode, it won't really help us fix the problem - then it's not really worth me wasting time trying to test this. Unless I'm missing a point to this test?

Comment: what I meant was compatibility mode on win 7 machine which is available on the higher flavors like the ultimate. It would use the CPUs virtualization(if available) so that it doesn't slow down your machine.
And yes, it is weird that it tried to load the pdb in game.
Did you examine the same(granny.dll) on your collegue's machine? 
Try to get his version of the dll and make it work.

Comment: I see there aren't too many people complaining about this. So probably this could be a one off configuration issue.

Please see if this helps, although looks like they're just generic steps to resolve dll issues and not specific to granny.dll:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/granny-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm

Answer (score 0):

You might try contacting the vendor of Granny 3D, since it is a $12000 product.  They may be willing and able to provide a couple of tips to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL has been built with Visual Studio 6.0 as indicated by the NB10 flag.